# Draw shaded area around GMSPolyline

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a `GMSPolyline` already drawn on a `GMSMapView`. I'd like to draw a shaded area around its path, with a 1 mile offset on each side.

I understand I need to create a `GMSPolygon`, but I am not sure what's the best way to calculate the polygon's path.

Comment: Have you tried using GMSMapPointDistance? you need to use [`FOUNDATION_EXPORT double GMSMapPointDistance(GMSMapPoint a,GMSMapPoint b )`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils#ga79d6d839aa13496078d0f2f47ee3832f) ? It returns the length of the segment [a, b] in projected space. The `length is computed` along the short path between the points potentially crossing the date line.

Comment: I actually need the opposite of this function: a function that takes a distance and returns a point on the map. Is there anything like that?

Comment: GMSGeometryOffset give you the coordinate of a point given a starting point, a direction and a direction (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#ga8d6fb874513718f8325ebca9615b051e)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out!